# Mi código no reconoce un valor pasado por medio de la variable $_GET

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un paso de información por medio de la variable $_GET, para de esta manera obtener tal valor y realizar una consulta en base de datos con ese valor en específico.

El problema es que al pasar la información y tratar de recuperarla en la siguiente pagina, PHP me envia el siguiente error:

> **Notice: Undefined index: id-categoria in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rede/main/vistas/paginas/modulos/subcategorias-body.php
>   on line 3**

No sé si deba a que estoy pasando el valor de manera incorrecta, o quizá el método que uso para recuperarlo no es el correcto, espero puedan ayudarme con eso.

Les dejo el código de la página desde la cual se emite la variable GET:

```
<?php 

$categorias = ControladorCatalogo::ctrMostrarCategorias();
//echo '<pre class="bg-white">'; print_r($categorias[4][3]); echo '</pre>';
$contadorCategoria = 1;

?>

    <?php foreach ($categorias as $categoria): ?>

        <section class="row content-central">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-xl-12">
            <div class=" bg-img-<?php echo $contadorCategoria; ?>">
                <!-- Imagen -->
            </div>
            <div class="showback">
                <a href="<?php echo $ruta; ?>subcategorias?id-categoria=<?php echo $categoria['id']; ?>">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><?php echo $categoria['categoria']; ?></button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </section>

    <?php $contadorCategoria++; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    </section>
</section>
```

Y la página a donde se redirige al usuario, donde intento recuperar el valor pasado y enviarlo a traves de un método:

```
<?php 

$idCategoria = $_GET["id-categoria"];

$subcategorias = ControladorCatalogo::ctrMostrarSubcategorias($idCategoria);
//echo '<pre>'; print_r($subcategorias); echo '</pre>';

?>

<section class="row justify-content-around content-central">
    <div class="showback col-12">
        <div>
            <?php foreach ($subcategorias as $subcategoria) : ?>

                <a href="<?php echo $ruta;?>micrositios?subcategoria=<?php echo $subcategoria['id']; ?>">
                <h4><?php echo $subcategoria['subcategoria']; ?></h4>
                </a>
                <hr>

            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Espero haberme dado a entender y puedan ayudarme.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Muestra como llega la ruta completa

Comment: Ese guión en `id-categoria` tiene pinta de que cae a manos del escapado URL y llega de otra forma a tu `$_GET`. Revisa haciendo `print_r($_GET)` en el script que recibe para que veas qué es lo que llega

Comment: @Alfabravo eso mismo pensé, pues entonces que haga el `print_r` o qué directamente intente pasarlo con otro nombre

Comment: Si realizas una instrucción `var_dump($_GET);`, ¿qué resultados arroja?, por favor compártelo en tu pregunta o como comentario. (No me di cuenta y preguntamos los mismo los 3)

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, pero al parecer el problema se debía a una regla que yo mismo realice en el htaccess del servidor al iniciar el desarrollo, pero no lo recordé hasta que ahorita volví a ingresar al htaccess para otras modificaciones. Para aclarar, la regla es la siguiente: "RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?pagina=$1", la cual justamente cambia los valores después del valor enviado via $_GET